# google libphonenumber get only mobile numbers from contacts

Tags: android, libphonenumber

I'm using libphonenumber to format phonenumbers in contacts. Is there any way to display only mobile numbers like WhatsApp? no local phone numbers.

The only idea I have is to have a list with all mobile area codes like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_number_series_by_country and check every number but this is a bit complicated I think.

Answer (score 4):

found the answer...

```
PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType nrtype = phoneUtil.getNumberType(NumberProto);
if (nrtype.name() == PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType.MOBILE) {
}
```

Comment: maybe should be : `if(nrtype == PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType.MOBILE)`

Answer (score -1):

```
Uri personUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, personId);

Uri phonesUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(personUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
String[] proj = new String[] {Phones._ID, Phones.TYPE, Phones.NUMBER, Phones.LABEL}

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(phonesUri, proj, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer